# FileSystemApi and writableStream

Tags: file-upload, html5-filesystem, native-file-system-api-js

I'm trying to use the FileSystem API to write an uploaded file on a SPA to a Local sandboxed FileSystem using the FileSystem API.

The File Is uploaded with drop acion and I can get the `File` object array in the call back.
From the `File` I can get the `ReadableStream` calling the `stream` method (yes, it return only readable sream).

Considering that the uploaded file could be big enough, I would go for a streaming than loading entirely into a blob and then writing into FileSystem api.

So, following the docs the steps are:

1. get a `FileSystem` (DOMFileSystem) through the async `webkitRequestFileSystem` call.
2. get the prop `root` that is a FileSystemDirectoryEntry
3. create a file through `getFile` (with flag `create:true`) that returns (async) a `FileSystemFileEntry`

Now from the FileEntry I can get a FileWriter using `createWriter` but it is obsolete (in MDN), and in any case it is a FileWriter while I would look to obtain a `WritableStream` instead in order to use the `pipeTo` from the uploaded file Handler->ReadableStream.

So, I see that in the console the class (interface) `FileSystemFileHandler` is defined but I cannot understand how to get an instance from the `FileSystemFileEntry`. If I can obtain a `FileSystemFileHandler` I can call the `createWritable` to obtain a `FileSystemWritableFileStream` that I can "pipe" with the ReadStream.

Anyone who can clarify this mess ?

references:
https://web.dev/file-system-access/
https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#filesystemhandle
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the solution in your "references" links at the bottom. Specifically, this is the [section](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#creating-or-accessing-files-and-folders-in-a-directory) to read. You can create files or directories like so:

```js
// In an existing directory, create a new directory named "My Documents".
const newDirectoryHandle = await existingDirectoryHandle.getDirectoryHandle('My Documents', {
  create: true,
});
// In this new directory, create a file named "My Notes.txt".
const newFileHandle = await newDirectoryHandle.getFileHandle('My Notes.txt', { create: true });
```

Once you have a file handle, you can then pipe to it or write to it:

```js
async function writeFile(fileHandle, contents) {
  // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
  const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
  // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
  await writable.write(contents);
  // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
  await writable.close();
}
```

…or…

```js
async function writeURLToFile(fileHandle, url) {
  // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
  const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
  // Make an HTTP request for the contents.
  const response = await fetch(url);
  // Stream the response into the file.
  await response.body.pipeTo(writable);
  // pipeTo() closes the destination pipe by default, no need to close it.
}
```